# Определение предикативной основы

Tags: синтаксический-разбор, основа

> Если говорить о России, то вполне очевидно, что есть вопросы, которыми у нас получается заниматься и которые нам действительно интересны (потому как ценны), а есть те, что, в силу вышеупомянутых естественных причин, выходят не очень. **Первые**, если можно так выразиться, и **есть** материальная **составляющая** национальной идеи, то, на чем мы должны сосредоточиться в политике, экономике, культуре.

https://portal-kultura.ru/articles/opinions/336224-chto-delat-russkomu-cheloveku/

А вопрос будет такой: правильно ли я определила предикативную основу (выделенные слова) в предложении? Это и есть тот редкий случай употребления глагола-связки в настоящем времени?

Comment: Ещё в настоящем связка "значит".

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, что такое предикативная основа. Если речь идет об основе предложения, то да, выделенные слова являются основой предложения ( в данном случае подлежащее и составное именное сказуемое ). Да, ‟ есть ” в данном предложении глагол-связка в настоящем времени.